# Why we need to do retain for Objective-C object field?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

This is the code of the Delphi media player:

```
type
  TAVMedia = class(TMedia)
  private
    FPlayer: AVPlayer;
    FPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem;
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TAVMedia.Create(const AFileName: string);
var aURL: NSUrl;
begin
  inherited Create(AFileName);
  FPlayerItem := TAVPlayerItem.Wrap(TAVPlayerItem.OCClass.playerItemWithURL(URL));
  FPlayerItem.retain;
  FPlayer := TAVPlayer.Wrap(TAVPlayer.OCClass.playerWithPlayerItem(FPlayerItem));
  FPlayer.retain;
end;

destructor TAVMedia.Destroy;
begin
  FPlayer.release;
  FPlayer := nil;
  FPlayerItem.release;
  FPlayerItem := nil;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

I don't quite understand why they need to do `FPlayerItem.retain` and `FPlayer.retain`? `FPlayerItem` and `FPlayer` are object fields and not local variables so there is always a strong reference to them. So what is the purpose of the `retain` here?

It seems that doing `FPlayer.release;` will also deallocate the `FPlayerItem`, so when later `FPlayerItem.release;` is called sometimes it triggers access violation (strangely not always).

**Note**: i still can't understand why i have an eaccessviolation so i decided to put here the full code of exactly what i did :

```
type
  TMyMedia = class(TObject)
  private
    FPlayer: AVPlayer;
    FPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyMedia.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  P := TNSUrl.OCClass.URLWithString(StrToNSStr(aDataSource)); // Creates and returns an NSURL object initialized with a provided URL string
  if P = nil then raise EFileNotFoundException.Create(SFileNotFound); // If the URL string was malformed or nil, returns nil.
  aURL := TNSUrl.Wrap(P);
  try

    FPlayerItem := TAVPlayerItem.Wrap(TAVPlayerItem.OCClass.playerItemWithURL(URL));
    FPlayerItem.retain;

  finally
    aURL.release; // << if i don't do this then i will not have any exception at the end ??? 
    aURL := nil;  // <<
  end;


  FPlayer := TAVPlayer.Wrap(TAVPlayer.OCClass.playerWithPlayerItem(FPlayerItem));
  FPlayer.retain;
end;

destructor TAVMedia.Destroy;
begin

  ALLog('FPlayer.retainCount', inttostr(FPlayer.retainCount)); // => show 1
  ALLog('FPlayerItem.retainCount', inttostr(FPlayerItem.retainCount)); // => show 6

  FPlayer.release;
  FPlayer := nil;

  ALLog('FPlayerItem.retainCount', inttostr(FPlayerItem.retainCount)); // => show 1
  FPlayerItem.release; => here i receive Access violation at address 2156565 accessing address 68684458

  FPlayerItem := nil;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FPlayer` and `FPlayerItem` are Delphi object wrappers around Objective-C raw object pointers.

While both Delphi for iOS and underlying iOS frameworks use reference counting to manage lifetime of object instances all similarities end there. Those are two separate reference counting mechanisms.

While keeping strong reference to `FPlayer` and `FPlayerItem` ensures lifetime of the Delphi wrapper instances, calling `retain` increases reference count on wrapped Objective-C object instance and keeps that object instance alive during the lifetime of wrapper itself.

Without calling `retain` wrapped object could get released by OS while Delphi wrapper still uses it.

Of course, to decrease reference count on wrapped object it is necessary to use matching `release` call when wrapper is destroyed.

---

As to why exceptions happen during `FPlayerItem.release;` it is hard to tell. It could be threading issue, bug in FMX part or even underlying OS frameworks.

As far as wrapped Objective-C instances are concerned they keep their own strong references where needed so releasing order is not important as far as they are concerned and it is also unlikely that OS is the culprit here (I cannot say for sure).

But if I would have to write above destructor code I would use following pattern to avoid issues on Delphi side.

```
destructor TAVMedia.Destroy;
var
  tmpPlayer: AVPlayer;
  tmpPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem;
begin
  tmpPlayer := FPlayer;
  tmpPlayerItem := FPlayerItem;
  FPlayer := nil;
  FPlayerItem := nil;
  tmpPlayer.release;
  tmpPlayerItem.release;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Dalija, i understand now very well the necessary of calling retain. but this exception make me crazy. just before doing FPlayerItem.release i print FPlayerItem.retainCount and it's show 1. but as soon i do FPlayerItem.release i have an eaccessViolation :(

Comment: Do you have any callbacks or threads involved? If `FPlayerItem` is set to nil after you call `FPlayerItem.release` those can use `FPlayerItem` wrapper object that uses now no longer existing Objective-C instance.

Comment: nothing, i remove everything (all delegate, etc) to make the code the most simple as possible. i just edit this question to show you the full code. i can't understand ...

Comment: crazy it's seam it's because i do release of the NSUrl i used to create the playeritem ! i can't understand :(

Comment: That one is simple... you should not call release on that url because you never called retain on it.

Comment: thanks Dalija, as i understand i simply do no need to call release because it's seam that the fplayeritem will keep a strong reference to the url ..

Comment: Take a look at @SebastianZ answer. Also, take a look at Delphi's TAVMedia creation code. You are over complicating your object creation.

Answer (score 2):

`TNSUrl.OCClass.URLWithString` and `TAVPlayerItem.OCClass.playerItemWithURL` add the items to the autorelease pool. Therefore you have a retain count of 1. They will be released when the autorelease pool releases the items it contains, which usually happens after the current event finishes executing.

Therefore `FPlayerItem.retain` is needed because FPlayerItem should not be released after the function exits. It is assigned to `FPlayerItem`, so you want to keep it alive.

In general, if you create such a class with `Create`, `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, `new...` then retain is called for you. Then you need to call `release` or `autorelease`.

If you create such a class with the other functions like `fileUrlWithPath` then it is added to the autorelease pool. You still have a retain count of 1, but it will be released for you. If you also release it then you'll crash.

If you call `retain` on a class, then that call must be balanced with a `release`.